# How does Apple's website autoplay videos, if autoplay is disabled in iOS?

Tags: ios, html, ipad, video, autoplay

As I keep reading, there is no way to enable HTML5 video autoplay in iOS browsers.

So why does my older iPad (with iOS 8) autoplay this introductory video from e.g., http://www.apple.com/ipad-air-2/ ?

When inspecting this on desktop Chrome, I pause at a certain point and see that a script inserts a `<video>` element with a mp4 file, then removes it after animation finishes. I've examined their script file as well, but did not find a definite answer to this.

I wish to clarify that I do not initiate any action other than opening the url. I have purposefully avoided every contact (no tapping, touching, etc.).

Could someone with more video experience explain this?

Comment: is there a javascript library to replicate the feature ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been answered to me in a different place, so if someone stumbles upon this later on...

The short answer is that Apple does not show a video on a device such as iPad. They flash a series of JPEG images like a filmstrip, making it appear as though a video is being played. For a desktop browser, they would show a video file though.

Comment: And here's the exact explication of how  they did it: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1GWTMLjqQsQS45FWwqNG9ztQTdGF48hQYpjQHR_d1WsI